# Transfer from a Hungarian to an Austrian University for non European student

Tags: transfer-student, visa, austria

Can a non EU student transfer from a Hungarian university, for example Eötvös Loránd University, to an Austrian university, and if yes do you have to go through the same procedure that you would in your home country such as visa.

Comment: If you're a non-EU citizen you will certainly need a student visa for whichever country you want to study in. Your university may be able to give you more specific guidance.

Comment: @astronat thank you.